# For Loop in angular 2 throws Exception

Tags: javascript, angular

I have set up a bootstrap by following the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html).

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular 2 Quickstart</title>
        <!-- Angular is working on removing the traceur dependency -->
        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.sfx.dev.js"></script>
        <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="components/display.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <my-app></my-app>
        <display></display>
    </body>
</html>
```

display.js

```
function DisplayComponent() {
    this.myName = "Jim";
    this.trophies = 'laugh';
    this.dogs = ['this','is','it'];
}

DisplayComponent.annotations = [
    new ng.ComponentMetadata({
        selector: "display"
    }),
    new ng.ViewMetadata({
        template:
            '<input [(ng-model)]="myName" type="text">' +
            '<h2>{{ trophies }}</h2>' +
            '<p>name: {{ myName }}</p>' +
            '' +
            '<ul>' +
            '   <li *ng-for="#dog of dogs">' +
            '       {{ dog }}' +
            '   </li>' +
            '</ul>',
        directives : [ng.FORM_DIRECTIVES]
    })
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.bootstrap(DisplayComponent);
});
```

For some reason if I remove the for loop it works again and displays the first variables normally, so I guess its a syntax error, but it seems to match the 
[documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/displaying-data.html)

Comment: If you are on a older version of Angular 2, platform directives need to be imported similar to form directives. If you migrate to the latest,directives are available without import. Also the doc shows you need to do `directives: [angular.NgFor]`

Comment: Thank you! its not "angular.NgFor" anymore, but "ng.NgFor", post this as answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NB : I can't comment sorry for this full post.

Which version of angular are you using ?
Because the following stuff is working for me:

```
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular 2 Quickstart</title>
    <!-- Angular is working on removing the traceur dependency -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.47/angular2.sfx.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="display.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <display></display>
</body>
```

Comment: don't know, it gets generated by npm if you follow the quickstart, however it does work with either the generated version and using the ng.NgFor directive or by using your version of angular. Thanks!

Comment: alpha 48 seems to work too. 
https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.48/angular2.sfx.dev.js

Comment: Angular2 doc for javascript is not really up to date.
You'd better to look after docs for typescript or dart, imo.